# -moz-appearance:none still displays a checkbox

Tags: html, css, firefox, checkbox, mozilla

I want to create a custom checkbox for the following field:

```
<label class="cmfchklabel"><input type="checkbox" id="cmf-2" name="cmf[2][value][]" value="true" checked>New Year\'s Eve</label>
```

The field is populated from a plugin, so I can't alter that basic markup.

I figured out how to update the look of the checkbox in webkit browsers, but Firefox keeps displaying a checkbox, even when I set **-moz-appearance:none;**.

How can I update the look of my checkbox in Firefox with CSS, without changing my basic markup?

For reference, here's my current CSS for the checkbox:

```
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    background:#177dc0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:before {
    content:'';
    background:#361512;
    display:inline-block;
    height:11px;
    width:11px;
    margin-right:1px;
}
```

[Here's my problem in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nC8cq/).

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I decided to just use a the "[prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/)" jquery plugin. It's a very simple way to update checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

`none` does not appear to be a valid option for [`-moz-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance).

> Do not use this property on Web sites: not only is it non-standard,
>   but its behavior changes from one browser to another. Even the keyword
>   `none` does not have the same behavior on each form element across
>   different browsers, and some do not support it at all.

In fact, it appears that Firefox will not honour any CSS on your textbox input. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxcBM/1/), which displays the `:before` text in Chrome but not Firefox (v24).

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the visibility of the checkbox in Firefox, if not with "-moz-appearance"?

Comment: Well, there's always `display:none`. Then you can create your new checkbox UI within something like `<label for="myCheckbox" class="checkboxShim"></label>`.

Comment: You could also check out the [Mozilla Brick x-toggle](http://mozilla.github.io/brick/demos/x-tag-toggle/index.html). It's pretty experimental, but it looks like it will degrade more gracefully than prefixed CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the default markup–or I will, but only as a last resort. The dilemma is how to to use CSS to custom style the checkbox within the given markup. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

i tried everything to solve this issue in FF, but there is only 1 solution for Firefox

try this

**CSS**

```
.test_1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.myCheckbox input {
    display: none;
}

.myCheckbox span {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    background:#00F;
}

.myCheckbox input:checked + span {
    background:#0F0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="test">Label for my styled "checkbox"</label>
<label class="myCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test"/>
    <span style="border:#666 1px solid;">.</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution I came up with that sniffs out Firefox and uses an extra element to create an illusion.

The trick is to place the input above the extra element and then give the input an opacity of 0. You can then style the extra element to your liking and use adjacent sibling selectors to apply the "hover, checked or focus" pseudo classes.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="inputs">
    <i class="for_firefox"></i>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" value="no" name="inputs">
    <i class="for_firefox"></i>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    /* Sniff out Firefox */
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1){
        jQuery('html').addClass('firefox');
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    /* Default Styling */
    .container{
        position:relative;
        height:30px;
        width:50px;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]{
        -webkit-appearance:none;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        -ms-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;
        border:1px solid gray;
        background-color:#B7D1E2;
        position:relative;
        height:22px;
        width:22px;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked,
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus{
        background-color:orange;
    }

    .for_firefox{
        display:none;
    }


    /* Firefox Styling */
    .firefox input[type="checkbox"]{
        /* need to add a little width for a better clickable surface area */
        height:26px;
        width:26px;
        opacity:0;
        z-index:2;
    }

    .firefox .for_firefox{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
    }

    .firefox .answers input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .for_firefox,
    .firefox .answers input[type="checkbox"]:focus + .for_firefox {
        background-color:orange;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this helps someone!